# How to install Visual Studio Remote Tools on Server Core?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging, server-core

I'd like to install the Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 Remote Tools on a Windows 2012R2 Server running IIS 8.5.  This is a pretty simple process outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx

The problem I have is that the server I'm trying to installing this on is a Server Core, meaning, there is no GUI.  The Remote Tools application is an exe that only installs via GUI.

I've tried to install it with PowerShell and it just hangs.  I'm also not able to find the Remote Tools in Web Platform Installer to install it that way.  Extensive Googling has turned up nothing.

Does anyone know how to install the Visual Studio Remote Tools on a Server Core so that I can debug on my DEV server?  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Create a .bat file and enter the below.  (not PowerShell)  (Or just at the command line.)

rtools_setup_x64.exe" /install /quiet

word...

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted. I use this for installing onto my server core 2012 r2, no problem with it.
Used: en_remote_tools_for_visual_studio_2015_update_2_x64_8487100.exe

Comment: Be aware that even though you can install it this way, you'll still need to configure it and that will still require a GUI.

Comment: This doesn't even create the msvsmon.exe file. It's missing from the target folder. All I see are VsGraphicsRemoteEngine... files. It took running the executable 3 times just to get the base directory of Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 to even show up in docker.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install remote tools. Just copy msvsmon.exe, from your local Visual Studio installation. Then start it from remote powershell silently:

```
Start-Process -FilePath .\msvsmon.exe -ArgumentList '/nosecuritywarn /port:4022 /silent' -Verb runAs
```

Don't forget to open firewall port.

Comment: For VS2019, only the exe is not enough (haven't checked for VS2017, nor which files are actually needed).
Copying over a whole folder x64 (or x86, depending on target OS) within IDE/Remote debugger folder helped though! Thanks for this tip. We've just started using it on our testing stations, and automating it's deployment and controlling when to start remotely is a really welcome feature for the whole team! :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you can simply remote into the Core server.  When you do so, you'll get a command prompt only.  From there, CD to the directory where the remote tools install file is.  Execute the file by typing the file name at the command prompt, ie: rtools_setup_x64.exe.

This will run the installer, with a GUI, on the Core server.  Its that simple, I didn't think you'd be able to get the install wizard on a Core server, however you do.